# Finding the local network's IP and MAC with Wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark

I have a wireshark PCAP file, I want to find the MAC addresses and the private IP (local network IP address) of each of the devices in the network. When I see the ethernet tab under conversations, I can see the corresponding MAC addresses. I also see multiple IP addresses (multiple v4 and multiple v6) in the IP tabs corresponding to the MAC. Is it possible to have more than 1 local IP address per MAC? I understand there can be multiple IP addresses associated with a MAC but I was wondering on how to find those only in the local network.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have more than 1 local IP address per MAC?

Yes and it is more common than you think; however, I think the PCAP may be misleading you a bit.

For unicast IP addresses, multicast has different rules, there are two main reasons you would see two different IP addresses go to/from a certain MAC:

1. The associated interface has multiple IP addresses. Below is an example of a interface in linux having multiple addresses:

```
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:43:c6:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.110.106/24 brd 192.168.110.255 scope global ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.110.102/24 brd 192.168.110.255 scope global secondary ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe43:c6d5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So both `192.168.110.106` adn `192.168.110.102` map to the MAC address `00:0c:29:43:c6:d5`

2. The associated MAC Address is a router/gateway. In the above example lets assume `192.168.110.1` is the gateway and has a MAC address of `00:0c:29:43:c6:d6`. If `192.168.1.10` want to send a packet to `8.8.8.8` (or any IP not in `192.168.110.1`) then it will send the packets to MAC address `00:0c:29:43:c6:d6` but have the destination IP address still be `8.8.8.8`. So in your PCAP you will see `00:0c:29:43:c6:d6` associated with `8.8.8.8` even though the MAc address technically belongs to `192.168.110.1`.